# Java field references to replace error prone Strings

Tags: java, string, refactoring

In our projects we use Hibernate HQL and Orika extensively.
This makes refactoring a pain, because all the fields that are referred in Strings in the mapping break when editing a field name or deleting a field.

Two possible (partial) solutions to this problem are better unit test coverage and better IDE configuration, but I'd rather solve the problem at it's core and use direct field references instead of the Strings.

Are there any frameworks (similar to e.g. Lombok) that make it easier to use field references in mappings so that a refactor results in compile time errors instead of runtime errors?

update: I found out about the Hibernate Metamodel Generator that can create JPA 2 metamodels: http://hibernate.org/orm/tooling/
Maybe such a thing also exists for non DB related referencing?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you have a lot of hibernate HQL queries that look something like this: `"select fufu_field from myEntityImpl"` and your problem is that if you change the name "fufu_filed" to "yoyo_filed" you have to search all your query strings and change the values manually. And this is a problem. I am not familiar with any framework that would solve this problem for you but I would suggest that you define all your field names in `Static final String` variables. So then you in the above example you will need to re-write your query as follows:

```
final public static String FUFU_FIELD_NAME = "fufu_filed";
private String myQuery = "select " + FUFU_FIELD_NAME + " from myEntityImpl";
```

Now if you need change the name you only will need to change thew value of your static String FUFU_FIELD_NAME variable in one place, regardless of how mane times it is used. You can go even further and define your names in property files and once your server comes up it can read the values from property file and initialize your static variables. This way you won't even need to recompile your project - just change your property file and restart the server.

Comment: Thank you Michael for this tip. In cases of repetition of the field names we often do such a thing with final Strings already.